# How to user react native in-app purchase (NOT version 3)?

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase, product

I'm trying to develop an app with in-app purchases using react-native-iap (**version 2.4.3**).

The installation went fine and the product demo "android.test.purchase" works fine.
(It shows Fake visa with a mock payment).

But when I create an item with id: **item_1** in *Google Developer Console -> in-app products -> managed products* and then add it to my app, the app show the following error:

*Something went wrong on our end. Please try again.*

Note 1: the app is online on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.danielemenchetti.inapppurchase).

Note 2: the app is published as **com.danielemenchetti.inapppurchase**

Here I post my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

const items = Platform.select({
  ios: [
   'android.test.purchase'
  ],
  android: [
   'android.test.purchase', 
   'com.danielemenchetti.inapppurchase.item_1' 
  ]
 });


export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      count:0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RNIap.initConnection();
    RNIap.getProducts(items).then((products) => { 
    //handle success of fetch product list
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    })

  }


  buyExample = () => { 
    RNIap.buyProduct('android.test.purchased').then(purchase => {
      this.setState({count: this.state.count+1});
      console.log("State: " + this.state.count);

      RNIap.consumePurchase(purchase.purchaseToken);
      console.log(purchase);

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Catch: " + error.message);
    })
  }

  buyItem1 = () => { 
    RNIap.buyProduct('com.danielemenchetti.inapppurchase.item_1').then(purchase => {

      this.setState({count: this.state.count+1});
      console.log("State: " + this.state.count);

      RNIap.consumePurchase(purchase.purchaseToken);
      console.log(purchase);

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Catch: " + error);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop: 15,}}>
          <View>
            <Button
              onPress={this.buyExample}
              title="Buy Example"
              color="#841584"
              accessibilityLabel="Buy more about this purple button"
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{marginLeft:15}}>
            <Button
              onPress={this.buyItem1}
              title="Buy Item 1"
              color="#841584"
              accessibilityLabel="Buy more about this purple button"
            />
          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: What is the product ID you see on the Google Console?

Comment: Hey Daniele, I want to ask you about something related to In-app purchase can you please tell me your email or Twitter so we can chat?

Comment: Hi Oliver, you can find my email address on my website http://www.danielemenchetti.com  . I hope I can help you! :)

Comment: @DanieleMenchetti I send to you, can you check out it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `real-native-iap` uses a module, you only need to fill out the `product id` value you created when you registered the product. You don't have to write `your package name` together.

The Test ID value created by the test is a guide to the name.

If your product ID is '**item_1**'

```js
const items = Platform.select({
  ios: [
   'android.test.purchase'
  ],
  android: [
   'android.test.purchase', 
   'item_1' 
  ]
 });
```